# Matrix of linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'd like to give the matrix in the canonical basis of :

$E=\mathbb{K_2}[X]$ and $L:E \rightarrow E$ the linear transformation $p \rightarrow q$ : $\forall x \ \in \ \mathbb{R}, q(x)=xp'(x)+p(x+1)$

I used to do it with linear transformation like $L(x,y,z)=(2x+y+z,x-3y)$ but how could we do it with polynoms ?

Thank you

Comment: Same way: define $L$ on the canonical basis of $E$ and put the result as a column.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : a basis of $\mathbb{K}_{2}[X]$ is given by $\lbrace 1,X,X^{2} \rbrace$. You need to :

- Compute $L(1)$, $L(X)$ and $L(X^2)$
- Express those vectors of $\mathbb{K}_{2}[X]$ in the canonical basis $\lbrace 1,X,X^{2} \rbrace$. The coefficients of $L(X^{k})$ $(0 \leq k \leq 2)$ in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{K}_{2}[X]$ will give you the $k$-th column of the matrix you want.